# Cant get my input to repeat or delete

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Alright, so what I am trying to do is get this program to ask user for input for quitting, running around randomly, or erasing whats been drawn already and running around randomly again.

I have the running around part down fine, I need help getting my input (called "message") to actually run option "w" and "e" so far all it does is draw a new random run. ( I may just have the wrong turtle command, I couldn't figure it out). I believe I am using the wrong words(if, while, elif) to get the menu to work properly. I also think the jumpto function is not working or I am resetting it inside my other function.

```
import turtle as t
import random as r
count=0
t.speed(0)
x=r.randint(1,100)
y=r.randint(1,100)
#----------------------------------------
""" sets the turtle to a new starting point"""
def jumpto(x,y):
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x,y)
    t.pendown()
    return None

def randomrun ():
    """runs turtle around 1000 steps randomly"""

    count=0
    while count <1000:
        count+=1
        t. forward (6)
        t.left(r.randint(0,360))#360 degree choice of rotation
    t.dot(10)#puts a dot at the end of the run of lines
    count=0#resets count so it can do it again
    x=r.randint(1,100)
    y=r.randint(1,100)
    message= input("q to quit \nw to walk randomly for 1000 steps \ne to erase screen and walk randomly ")
    return message
#-------------------------------------------
message= input("q to quit \nw to walk randomly for 1000 steps \ne to erase screen and walk randomly ")

if message =="w": 
   randomrun()
   jumpto(x,y)

if message == "q":
    print(" have a nice day")

if message== "e":
    t.clear()
    randomrun()
    jumpto(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `return` from `randomrun` is ignored.  Anyway, repeating the input prompt is a bad idea.  Remove it, and the `return`, from `randomrun` and end with an `input` loop.

```
while True:
    message = input("q to quit\n"  # use implicit string joining
                    "w to walk randomly for 1000 steps\n"
                    "e to erase screen and walk randomly\n"
                    "> ")[:1].lower()  # forgive non-exact input
    if message == "q":
        print("Have a nice day!")
        break
    elif message =="w": 
        randomrun()
        jumpto(x,y)
    elif message == "e":
        t.clear()
        randomrun()
        jumpto(x,y)
    else:
        print("Input not recognized; try again.")
```

Comment: Thanks kindly! only problem is, the first time the input is entered nothing happens and it asks for input again. then works

Comment: That puzzles me.  On Win 10 with 3.5.0, code works fine when run from IDLE.  Run, enter w in shell at prompt, watch random walk.

Comment: Also works when run from command line.  I do have to click on console or shell to shift focus so input is accepted.  (Why mixing text and gui UIs is not so good.)  But this is not what you describe.